# how can I change charts in PPT using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts, powerpoint

I have the following code, which exports all my graphics to a slide in powerpoint

```
Dim PPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim SldIndex As Integer

Dim Chrt As ChartObject
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet

Set PPTApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPTApp.Visible = True
    
Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)


  
For Each WrkSht In Worksheets
        
    For Each Chrt In WrkSht.ChartObjects
    
        Chrt.Copy
        
        PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
        
        
    
   
        Next Chrt
        
    Next WrkSht


End Sub
```

I need to scale and change their position so that I can arrange them on the slide. do I do this for VBA within excel or VBA within powerpoint?

And his is an exemple, so how the VBA export my graphs:

[image: graphs in a slide]

Comment: To answer your question, you would do this with VBA within powerpoint

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim obj As PowerPoint.ShapeRange, y As Integer, x As Integer
x = 100: y = 0
For Each WrkSht In Worksheets
        
    For Each Chrt In WrkSht.ChartObjects
    
        Chrt.Copy
        Set obj = PPTSlide.Shapes.Paste
                
        ' scale
        obj.Height = 150
        obj.Width = 150
    
        ' position
        obj.Left = x
        obj.Top = y
        y = y + 200
    
    Next Chrt
        
Next WrkSht
```